# Changing Figure Size Bar Plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, bar-chart

How would I make the figure larger to clearly display all my values along the y axis.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['mass_shootings.csv']))
df.State.value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `figsize` argument. E.g.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['mass_shootings.csv']))
df.State.value_counts().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(20, 6))
```

Read more on https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html